# Aptana Studio 3.4 HTML preview display error

Tags: aptana3

I just updated from Aptana Studio 3.3 to build: 3.4.0.201304151603. I am on a Windows 7 x64 system.

After updating, the HTML Preview window no longer behaves correctly. The HTML content is rendered in the right half of the preview window, and the left half is left blank, except for the URL bar controls. The URL to the file being previewed is not shown in the URL field.

[image: Windows HTML Preview after 3.4 update]

Wondering if one of my other plugins was causing the problem, I tried a fresh install with no plugins beyond those installed along with Aptana Studio. The behavior is the same.

Wondering if it was a Windows issue, I tried installing Studio 3.4 on a Ubuntu 12.10 virtual machine, but the behavior is the same.

[image: Ubuntu HTML Preview after 3.4 update]

Any suggestions?

Comment: Filed as APSTUD-7832 in Jira.