# Aptana is opening multiple browser previews

Tags: browser, split, aptana

I installed Aptana on my work computer today, but when I open the preview it seems to open two browsers. One of which showing the page I requested, while the one on the left is just an empty browser window. I've google'd my face off but can't seem to find anyone with the same issue. I know this is probably just a simple setting but it's eluding me. Here's a screencap of the issue.

http://imgur.com/b0rbvKQ

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See my comment here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16255709/aptana-3-studio-preview-shared-with-web-browser#comment23311287_16255709 and the original here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113110/aptana-studio-3-4-html-preview-display-error