# Configuring the Aptana preview editor

Tags: configuration, aptana

I can't get my preview editor to display HTML pages in the full preview screen. Instead, it shows the page in the right half of the screen, and the Nav bar and control bar in the left half of the screen:

[image]

I've poked around as much as I can, but I can't find anything about configuring the preview editor. Anyone know if there's anything I can do to change this?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a bug in the latest release. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113110/aptana-studio-3-4-html-preview-display-error#comment23012672_16113110

Comment: Sarah, thanks. If you want to reply to this as a full-blown response, I'll be happy to mark it as answered and up your reputation :) PS - love your website.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several other questions on the site covering this same issue. I would try to flag this question as a duplicate for its "resolution", but I cannot find any copies of this question that have an accepted answer.

The latest release of Aptana 3.4 has a bug which was filed as APSTUD-7832 in Jira after this post: [Aptana Studio 3.4 HTML preview display error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16113110/aptana-studio-3-4-html-preview-display-error#comment23012672_16113110)

Hopefully it will be back in business soon.

Comment: Let's hope this one prevents all of the other dupes :)

Thanks again.

Comment: Just updated my version to 3.4.1 and the issue still exists. Bummer.